# Display field in TCA of pages based on the previous field value

Tags: typo3

I would like to achieve that my field in TCA will be shown or hidden based on my previous field value. How can I do that? I can do it in javascript, but is possible to include a javascript in TCA?

Here user choose value:

```
$fields = array(
'question_field' => array(
    'label' => 'user choose',
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'items' => array(
        array('Yes','1'),
        array('No','0'),
        ),
    ),
)
```

);

if the value is yes, i would like to display second field:

```
$fields = array(
'second_field' => array(
    'label' => 'second question',
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'items' => array(
        array('Yes','1'),
        array('No','0'),
        ),
    ),
)
```

);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So in your case, it will be adding this line
`'displayCond' => 'FIELD:question_field:=:1',`
so final solution will looks like this:

```
$fields = array(
'second_field' => array(
    'label' => 'second question',
    'displayCond' => 'FIELD:question_field:=:1',
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'items' => array(
        array('Yes','1'),
        array('No','0'),
        ),
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `displayCond` for that. It‘s well documented with examples in [TCA documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/singlehtml/Index.html#displaycond). Please note you can switch TYPO3 version of documentation page bottom left to match your version.

Comment: Thanks! I am going to check it.