# Dynamically display fields in TCA

Tags: typo3

Servus,
Based on the previous question [Display field in TCA of pages based on the previous field value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43070362/display-field-in-tca-of-pages-based-on-the-previous-field-value/43071719#43071719), I am wondering how I can dynamically show the next field with `displayCond` because of my field shows, only when I hit the save and reload the page. So it is not dynamical. I would like to have when a user changes it than in next second will be displayed another field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don‘t think there‘s an API for doing what you plan. You can improve the situation a bit if you set `'onChange' => 'reload'` for `question_field` (directly in the array, not in `config`).

This will show a modal prompt asking for reload in order to apply changes in display conditions. Can get nasty, too :-(

Comment: yea, thanks for the help. thats a pitty that there is no javascript option